pySpark RDD whitelisted Class issues
I was used below code before enabled unity catalog cluster in azure databricks notebook but after changed shared users enabled cluster. i could not able to use below logic, how should we achieve similar logic in my notebook after enabled unity catalog cluster.
list= df_list.rdd.map(lambda x: x[0]).collect()
hlist = df_list.rdd.map(lambda x: x[1]).collect()

unity catalog enabled cluster notebook error:

py4j.security.Py4JSecurityException: Method public org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD.rdd() is not whitelisted on class class org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD


Low-level APIs such as RDD and Spark Context won't work in using Unity Catalog - Shared Compute.
You need to use a Single User cluster or migrate your code to use High-level Dataframe APIs.
See whether this helps.
result_list = df_list.select(df_list.columns[0]).collect()
result_list = [row[df_list.columns[0]] for row in result_list]

This page has all such examples, you can use it for your reference.
https://python.plainenglish.io/databricks-non-rdd-scripts-for-rdds-1ba15872822e

hi, after use below code, my i issues resolved

tableList = [row.outTable for row in df_tableList.collect()]
hKeyList = [row.bkColumn for row in df_tableList.collect()]

but i am getting another issues if we use    spark._sc._gateway.jvm.java.util.Properties()    spark._sc._gateway.jvm.java.sql.DriverManager

py4j.security.Py4JSecurityException: Method public synchronized void java.util.Hashtable.putAll(java.util.Map) is not whitelisted on class class java.util.Properties

sc  is also a low-level API and won't work. What are you using this for?
Share the piece of code, so we can try for alternatives.

its already shared above comments....... spark._sc._gateway.jvm.java.util.Properties()  ...... spark._sc._gateway.jvm.java.sql.DriverManager

props = spark._sc._gateway.jvm.java.util.Properties()
props.putAll(connectionProperties)
driver_manager = spark._sc._gateway.jvm.java.sql.DriverManager
con = driver_manager.getConnection(jdbcUrl,props)

Hi All, any update for i requested solutions

Sorry, can you try using DataFrames?
props = {"user":"..", "pass":"..", "driver":".."}
df = spark.read.format("jdbc") 
.option("url", jdbc_url) 
.option("dbtable", "your_table_name") 
.options(**props) 
.load()
